# What's a good emulator to port to Silverlight 3?

Tags: c#, silverlight, emulation

I'm thinking about attempting a port of an existing emulator code base to Silverlight 3.  There appears to be enough functionality with WritableBitmap and the new sound classes to make a port feasible.  Is anyone familiar with an emulator that's open source and might not be too hard to port?  I'd really like to focus on moving the media aspects of the source to SL more than the complexities of porting some awkward ASM code to C#.  I guess if I could find some source that's already in C# it might be ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with a good 'ol NES emulator...

[SharpNES](http://forge.novell.com/modules/xfmod/project/?sharpnes) is C#/Mono so while it might not be directly port-able, it should be a good start.

[vNES](http://www.virtualnes.com/) is a Java NES emulator intended to be run in an applet. It's source is freely available under GPL. Not C#, but might be worth looking at for ideas.

Comment: SharpNES turned out to be quick enough to port most of the code on my lunch break.  Should be able to easily replace the 1 blitting function with some WriteableBitmap calls.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking for interested folks to bring http://silverlightc64.codeplex.com up to full functionality. It's a C64 emulator. I just want to make sure that whoever contributes can make a real contribution :)

I use MediaStreamSource to output 50fps of video instead of using the writablebitmap. The advantage is if the client machine can't keep up, MSS will handle dropping frames.

Pete

Comment: Hey Pete, thanks for the link!  Maybe I'll see if I've got the chops to do something useful for the C64 project.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this C# gameboy emu:

http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=cvs&group_id=95094